# how to update sqlite datetime format

Tags: sqlite

I was searching to change my `Order_Date` format to an existing data.

I have 3000+ rows in my `SQLite` database.

I want to update my all rows from this format `29/09/2018 1:03:44 AM` to this `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` is there any way to do this?

My `Order_Date` Column Datatype is `TEXT`

So far i tried

```
UPDATE Orders SET Order_Date = strftime(Order_Date, '%Y-%M-%d %H:%m')
```

But the above query updated my all rows to null

Comment: Are you sure you want seconds and not minutes?

Comment: I want minutes I updated my question

Comment: Sqlite's built-in string functions are pretty limited. I'd just add a custom user defined function in the language of your choice that transforms the timestamp strings and use that in an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following may suit.

```
UPDATE ORDERS
    SET order_date =
    CASE 
        WHEN length(order_date) = 21 AND substr(order_date,20,2) = 'AM' THEN
            substr(order_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(order_date,4,2)||'-'||substr(order_date,1,2)||' '
                ||'0'||substr(order_date,12,4)
        WHEN length(order_date) = 21 AND substr(order_date,20,2) = 'PM' THEN
            substr(order_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(order_date,4,2)||'-'||substr(order_date,1,2)||' '
                ||CAST(CAST(substr(order_date,12,1) AS INTEGER) + 12 AS TEXT)||substr(order_date,13,3)
        WHEN length(order_date) = 22 AND substr(order_date,21,2) = 'AM' THEN
                substr(order_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(order_date,4,2)||'-'||substr(order_date,1,2)||' '
                ||substr(order_date,12,5)
        WHEN length(order_date) = 22 AND substr(order_date,21,2) = 'PM' THEN 
                substr(order_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(order_date,4,2)||'-'||substr(order_date,1,2)||' '
                ||CAST(CAST(substr(order_date,12,2) AS INTEGER) + 12 AS TEXT)||substr(order_date,14,3)
    END
;
```

This caters for the varying length due to the hour being 1 or 2 digits. **However, it would not cope if the day were likewise 1 digit when it is less than 10.**

Embedding this into a test as per :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (order_date TEXT);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES
    ('29/09/2018 1:03:44 AM'),
    ('29/09/2018 1:03:44 PM'),
    ('29/09/2018 11:03:44 AM'),
    ('29/09/2018 11:03:44 PM');

UPDATE ORDERS
    SET order_date =
    CASE 
        WHEN length(order_date) = 21 AND substr(order_date,20,2) = 'AM' THEN
            substr(order_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(order_date,4,2)||'-'||substr(order_date,1,2)||' '
                ||'0'||substr(order_date,12,4)
        WHEN length(order_date) = 21 AND substr(order_date,20,2) = 'PM' THEN
            substr(order_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(order_date,4,2)||'-'||substr(order_date,1,2)||' '
                ||CAST(CAST(substr(order_date,12,1) AS INTEGER) + 12 AS TEXT)||substr(order_date,13,3)
        WHEN length(order_date) = 22 AND substr(order_date,21,2) = 'AM' THEN
                substr(order_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(order_date,4,2)||'-'||substr(order_date,1,2)||' '
                ||substr(order_date,12,5)
        WHEN length(order_date) = 22 AND substr(order_date,21,2) = 'PM' THEN 
                substr(order_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(order_date,4,2)||'-'||substr(order_date,1,2)||' '
                ||CAST(CAST(substr(order_date,12,2) AS INTEGER) + 12 AS TEXT)||substr(order_date,14,3)
    END
;
SELECT * FROM orders;
```

Results in :-

[image]

Comment: I don't know how this query is working but it solved my problem, I want to learn about this number after the Column `20,2`? kindly suggest me any link where I can learn this strings.

Comment: @BryanBell Basically there are 4 permutations. 2 according to the length of the entire value (21 if the hour is a single digit, 22 if the hour is 2 digits). If the entire length is 21 then characters 20-21 `substr(order_date,20,2)` then it will be either PM or AM likewise when the entire length is 22 then characters 21-22 will be either AM or PM. So that's 4 permutations and hence the 4 **WHEN** clauses.

Answer (score 1):

My assumptions: year is 4 digits and each of month, day, hour, minutes 2 digits.  
I tested the below code and it seems to work:

```
UPDATE Orders 
    SET Order_Date = 
        substr(datetime(substr(Order_Date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(Order_Date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(Order_Date, 1, 2) || ' ' 
        || substr(Order_Date, 12, 2) || ':' || substr(Order_Date, 15, 2), 
        '+' || 
        CASE substr(Order_Date, length(Order_Date)-1)
            WHEN 'PM' THEN '12'
            ELSE '0' 
        END 
        || ' hours'), 1, 16)
```

Comment: Then my assumptions are not valid, `year is 4 digits and each of month, day, hour, minutes 2 digits` are they?

Comment: Yes year is 4 digits and minutes is 2 digits, I want to format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`

Comment: This means that all your dates are exactly **22** chars long and the last **2** chars are AM or PM.

Comment: Current Format is `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`

Comment: I know that. Just execute this query: `SELECT DISTINCT length(Order_Date) FROM Orders`. If it outputs only 22 then the above code should work. If not this means that there are months or days or hours or mins with only 1 digit and the code fails.

Comment: The output is `length(Order_Date)
16
21
22`

Comment: This means that your format varies and this is why the code fails. It should work though for all the rows that have dates with length 22.

Comment: so what should I do? kindly help me in that otherwise my all data will be lost or I will need to update the rows one by one.

Comment: I tried this query it formatted the date correctly but can you help to correct the time as well `UPDATE Orders 
    SET Order_Date = 
        substr(Order_Date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(Order_Date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(Order_Date, 1, 2) || ' ' 
        || substr(Order_Date, 12, 2) || ':' || substr(Order_Date, 15, 2)
        WHERE Order_Date LIKE '29/09/2018 1:03:44 AM'` This query convert my `29/09/2018 1:03:44 AM` to `2018-09-29 1::3:`

Comment: The format of the date is not standard, it is not **dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss tt** as you said, this is why it is very difficult to solve it by an sql statement. Post another question and ask for a solution via a programming language like java or c++ that could manipulate the data.

Comment: I know it's not standard that's why I need to change it.